# Strip default HTML code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a web form where I'll perform some background action based on the GET parameter through jQuery and will print 1 or 0. But the problem - ASP.NET is printing lots of HTML by default even when no such code exist in the Markup window

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<%
  try
  {
    int cID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["cid"].ToString());
    //do some job and print 1 or 0
  }
  catch { }
%>
```

But in the output window I see HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: That markup is the base Html required to define a page, give or take.  Why is it a problem?  It won't cause anything to be displayed to the end-user except for a blank page.

Comment: I just need to have defined output not HTMLs :(

Comment: It sounds like you're creating a web service, not a web page.  Could you create a service and customise the output of that, instead?

Comment: Actually I was doing it the PHP way (:
Will try that, but have never tried using Service

Comment: @DanPuzey Can you please show me a sample **Hello World** example ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use an ashx (Add New Item > Generic Handler) handler instead of aspx form

inside the process request change the response Mime type to text/plain and simply write the query string value to the response

MyHandler.ashx.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for MyHandler
/// </summary>
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(context.Request.QueryString["cid"]);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

getting the value client-side with jQuery:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "MyHandler.ashx?cid=10",
            contentType: "text/plain",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        })
```